# Create export to CSV button in wordpress backend for custom post, taxonomy, and meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a button to export data to CSV file, currently it works only for custom post type and custom meta. But when I try to export with custom tax, it broken the site.

The problem I've found is when I add this code in my fputcsv array:

```
get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'custom-tax' )
```

This is my function.php file:

```
    # Adding button in backend
    add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'add_export_button' );
    function add_export_button() {
        $screen = get_current_screen();

        if (isset($screen->parent_file) && ('edit.php?post_type=custom-post-type' == $screen->parent_file)) {
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="export_all_posts" id="export_all_posts" class="button button-primary" value="Export All Posts">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function($) {
                    $('#export_all_posts').insertAfter('#post-query-submit');
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }

    # Adding export function for custom post,
    add_action( 'init', 'func_export_all_posts' );
    function func_export_all_posts() {
        if(isset($_GET['export_all_posts'])) {
            $arg = array(
                    'post_type' => 'custom-post-type',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                );

            global $post;
            $arr_post = get_posts($arg);
            if ($arr_post) {

                header('Content-type: text/csv');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="wp.csv"');
                header('Pragma: no-cache');
                header('Expires: 0');

                $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

                fputcsv($file, array('post_id', 'post_title', 'custom_meta', 'custom_tax'));

                foreach ($arr_post as $post) {
                    setup_postdata($post);
                    fputcsv($file, array( get_the_id(), get_post_field( 'post_title', get_post() ), get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_meta', true ), get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'custom-tax' ) ));
                }

                exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help with the custom taxonomy part? Thank you.